# Don't highlight HTML areas on editing CSS rules in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

On the latest Chrome version, we got some powerful CSS tools to create rules using buttons and a highlight on every affected area when editing any rule in the inspector, this is very useful, but also some annoying to design a website.

If I am editing a rule like `padding` or `margin`, it shows a green or orange area around the element, for me is hard to say where is the border exactly with this colored area, I prefer to see the "REAL" result.

On the following image I am editing the padding and I can not see the border.

[image]

If I want to edit the border color to a different color, the line color turn into orange, then I can not see the color I am changing.

On the following image I am changing the border color to gray, as you can see it shows an orange border instead.

[image]

**How do I disable/turn off this feature?**

Google Chrome Version 73.0.3683.86

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot change/ turn off this feature without compiling your own version of Chromium, which I don't think is a good idea. From a FE point of view, the question is why you would care about this? No matter what the color of a property is, you can safety follow the design guide / spec from the layout you have and that's it. Honestly sometimes for debugging purpose, this might bothers me but it's not a big deal, as long as the result achieves, you can have another color of choice to test and replace it with a proper one later.

Comment: @starmin can you provide code or a fiddle link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using bit older version, this has been fixed in newer versions. `Chrome Version 74.0.3729.169` and `Canary Version 77.0.3812.0`.

after updating chrome, if you still face this issue, here is the work around.

With mouse hover over selected element in DOM Tree.

[image]

---

Without mouse hover over selected element in DOM Tree.

[image]

---

You just need to remove hover from element selection.

Comment: You are totally right, updating my chrome fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

`<div unselectable="on">Test Text</div>`

This is what i could find for you, it might just work for you.
Full post here: [How to stop highlighting of a div element when double-clicking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018324/how-to-stop-highlighting-of-a-div-element-when-double-clicking)